# How can I really edit image by using UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage to retrieve a UIImage object that contains the final image after the user moved and/or scaled it. However, when I go to the simulator, select the image I want, and then I don't find any options for editing the picture. It seems like .editedImage is same as .originalImage. I tried to find a way to edit the image with the UIImage picker controller such as cropping, scaling, etc. but my simulator doesn't have that option. How can I add some functions to edit an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step-1:** Tap and hold the **Option key** `(⌥)` on the keyboard and click on the selected image on the Simulator. You'll see two Solid, Gray buttons showing up where your mouse cursor is, just the same as a user would use their Index finger and Thumb to `Pinch and Zoom` an image (screenshot attached).

[image]

**Step-2:** Drag the image on the Simulator. You'll be able to crop the selected image by zooming in (screenshot attached). Can move the image also, by unholding the **Option key** `(⌥)` from your keyboard.

[image]

**Step-3:** Finally, the `info[.editedImage]` will get the user's edited/modified image in the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.

Comment: That makes sense. So I don't need to do any code thing... Thanks

Comment: Right... Since Simulators have a way to display those iOS gestures.
Glad to help! :)